# Keep user data when migrating map from Realms to the server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I'm planing to migrate Minecraft Realms map to my server. I've managed to migrate the map, but the problem is that players data is not migrated.

Is it possible to migrate map from Realms with all players inventory, ender chest contents and experience, so when the same player from Realms logs into the server, he will keep all his inventory? What would be the process to do that?

Only solution I have found so far is to ask all players to move all their possession into a chest on Realms and pick them up on the server after migration. Problem with this approach is to get all players do that within reasonable time range.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: quote : " I've managed to migrate the map, but the problem is that players data is not migrated." have you tried it already ? in the map folder there should be a subfolder named players (or playersdata with more recent versions), which is supposing to contain a .dat file for every players, therefore their inventory, xp, spawn .... source [player.dat](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format)

Comment: Yes, I moved all files from Realms, but player inventory wasn't there when I logged into server.

Comment: maybe Realms is using a different type of map folder than bukkit or vanilla servers. Have you checked the subfolders , are there somewhere the .dat files ?

Comment: I have been trying to determine if it's possible to take a Realms map and migrate it to a server... this worked for you? I tried running a Realms map backup on Spigot and it wouldn't work at all, the map data seems to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check your **server.properties** on new server if there is this:

```
online=true
```

If there is `false`, then this error can occur. Some providers set this as default (which is really bad practice), so you could miss it.

The problem is that since 1.7.10, Minecraft uses UUID - identification numbers, that are bound to player's account and not a name - therefore you can change your name, but even then you are same person for servers.

However, this works only if server does authenticate with Mojang session servers (so is `online=true`). It gets player's UUIDs from those servers, therefore can store player's statistics and inventory (and all other player's data) in files named in format of `<UUID>.dat`.

However if server is in `online=false`, it has no way to get UUIDs, so it computes them itself from player's name. And those two UUIDs **do NOT match**! So same player will be someone totally different for server, dependant on aforementioned settings, which will lead into lose of inventories etc.

Realms should be `online=true` by definition, so you need your server use same system. Then it should give respective players their old stats&inventories. (IF you managed to copy the data. They are located in world's folder)

---

DO NOTE:

Setting this value to false means that players who did not bought the game can login to the server (and possibly steal someone's person), which is against the licence of Minecraft. You shall not let something like that happen. Also it is really big danger for server security, because anyone can login on admin's accout with OP and do really bad stuff.

Never use `online=false` except situations without internet. (for example you play on countryhouse via lan only)

Comment: Server is hosted at location-minecraft.com. I can't find server.properties file anywhere on FTP. Where should it be located? In log files I have found `**** SERVER IS RUNNING IN OFFLINE/INSECURE MODE!` so that might be the case.

Comment: Yes, this line in log is there only when the server is in online=false. server.properties should be located in the main folder of server, however it depends how this particular host wants you to access it (they can disable you to see/change it). Try to look if they have some setups outside of files, for example as a part of website control panel. If not, try to contact them and let them change it for you, it is important settings. :)

Comment: That was it. There was an option - deactivate illegal versions. Thank you.